# Is there any mathematical proof of Newton law of universal gravitation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Is there any way to derive mathematically Newton's law of universal gravitation ?

How this formula so exactly follow the law of gravation?

If this is just a guess then why it is so accurate?

$F = Gm1m2/R2$

Comment: Duplicate of 

http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137768 
and other link therein.

Comment: Sorry for labelling it as duplicate. But please make your question clear. What you are saying and asking are totally meddled with each other and write a strong title; I thought you were asking that question but after reading the body, it is completely different. But since you are new, be aware next time!

Comment: I would guess it's because the most obvious application of Newton's law is to calculate the force on something orbiting a much heavier object in a roughly circular orbit. (E.g. planets around the Sun, or satellites around planets). In this case $r$ is the radius of the orbit.

Comment: Debating one notation over another is non-constructive and off-topic, cf. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/2451) meta post.

Comment: I prefer to that of @Nathaniel. However, I would say it is mostly due to historical reason. Old books wrote acceleration as $f$ but today we prefer $a$ to avoid confusion. However,it doesn't bother any physics.

Comment: There isn't a hint of that question in the question you wrote. If you had asked that, your question would have been closed as a duplicate of [Why are so many forces explainable using inverse squares when space is three dimensional?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47084/)

Answer (score 2):

Excluding *F*, *G*, *M*, and *m* (you've already used those names in this expression), you could label that distance any letter from *a* to *z* or from *A* to *Z* or from $\alpha$ to $\omega$. Or whatever. It doesn't matter. It's a variable.

That said, there are conventions. It's best not to call that distance *v*, for example. The symbol *v* usually means a velocity or speed, not a distance. With regard to distance, you can find textbooks, etc., that label the distance as *d*, and then you will see $F = GMm\,/\,d^2$. Denoting a distance as *d* or *r* is in line with the naming conventions.