# Inverse square law and the photon mass

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, mass

I have seen many questions about this, but haven't really found the answer I was looking for.

I was caught by an exercise that said:

> Consider two charges: $q$ (a test charge) and
>   $Q$, at $\vec{R}$ and $\vec{r}$, respectively.Assuming that the force
>   $Q$ exerts on $q$ is:
>
> \begin{equation} \vec{F}_{Q \rightarrow q} = \frac{1}{4 \pi
> \epsilon_0} \frac {q Q}{|\vec{r} - \vec{R}|^{2+\Delta}} \left[
>  \frac{\vec{r} - \vec{R}}{|\vec{r} - \vec{R}|}  \right] 
> \end{equation}
>
> If $\Delta \neq 0$, find the expression that allows you to obtain the
>   photon's mass from $\Delta$.

I have seen some answers using Yukawa's potential, and also an [article](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0026-1394/41/5/S04) about it (that my teacher mentioned), but I'd like to know a way (if there is) to obtain the photon's mass without using Yukawa's potential or the Proca equation.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22010/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic I have seen this answer and the articles cited, but I have not seen anything on them about the photon mass. Maybe I should take a closer look, but at first sight, it hasn't helped very much. Thank you, though.

Comment: I do not know of something other than Proca; depending on your level of mathematical expertise this might be a useful starting point: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.1003.pdf