# Exponents in physical laws

Tags: newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law

There are two very important laws in physics, namely the [Newton's law of universal gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) and the [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law), both of which contain a $r^{-2}$. I am curious about the exponent $2$ here.

There is already a well-answered question [The square in the Newton's law of Universal Graviation is Really a Square?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22010/the-square-in-the-newtons-law-of-universal-gravitation-is-really-a-square) about the $2$ in the Newton's law of Universal Graviation. It can be seen that historically there have been some attempts in modifying the the exponent $2$ there. I find the Betrand's Theorem explanation in the referred question quite convincing.

For the Coulomb's law, there are also attempts to modify the exponent $2$ and I think this [1970 PRD paper](https://www.princeton.edu/~romalis/PHYS312/Coulomb%20Ref/BartlettCoulomb.pdf) summarizes the effort to measure the exponent. In the 1970 experiment it is shown that the exponent deviates from $2$ by at most $1.3\times10^{-13}$. I don't know whether there are other more accurate results recently.

My question is, if the exponents in these two laws have been questioned about, are the exponents in other fundamental physical laws ever questioned by people and measured in the experiment (to verify they are integers, for example)? Or it is because in macroscopic world the only important fundamental interactions are gravitation and electromagnetic interaction so verifying the exponents in these two laws would suffice?

As it as been commented that this is like a listing question, I am going to further clarify the questions.

1. What is the reason behind the fact that there are many experiments measuring the **coefficients** in physical laws very accurately but there are quite few regarding the **exponents**?
2. Does it suffice to verify that the exponents are indeed $2$ in the two laws stated above to justify that the exponents used in other physical laws are what they are? Why is verifying the number $2$ in Coulomb's law (for example) so important that people are constantly doing experiments on it?

Sorry if I have some misunderstanding above, and if that is the case please point it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: I don't think it is true that there are not many experiments measuring exponents, (if anything I would say there are more of them; exponents are often much easier to calculate and measure) however we normally describe these experiments as "testing whether such and such equation is correct" rather than "measuring the exponent in such and such equation".

Comment: @Bysymmetry Thank you, I haven't thought of it that way and your comment certainly enlightened me. However I am still confused why the square in Coulomb's law is so important, I think there should be some theoretical explanation to it, possibly related to the axiomization of physics laws.